# Input redirection in find -exec option

Tags: bash, redirect, find

Why doesn't this command work?

```
find / -type f -name "*.c" -exec wc -c < \{} \;
```

I'm trying to hide the filename while showing number of characters

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

```
find / -type f -name "*.c" -exec wc -c {} + | awk '{print $1}'
```

---

`<` does not work because redirection applies to the `find` command itself. So what you can do is use `awk` to only print the first column

As pointed out by @Charles Duffy, this is a bit more efficient since it means we're only starting one `wc` process, and no shell wrapper, once per file (as the `awk` instance is shared, not invoked per-file).

Comment: This is a bit more efficient than the other solutions posted thus far, since it means we're only starting one `wc` process, and no shell wrapper, once per file (as the `awk` instance is shared, not invoked per-file).

Comment: That said, you could improve it further with `-exec wc -c {} +`, to pass multiple filenames to each instance of `wc`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the suggestion, added it!

Answer (score 2):

Use a bash command with `exec` like below

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec bash -c 'wc -c < "$1"' _ {} \;
```

In your case the redirection `<` applies to the find command itself resulting a *syntax error* as there is no file literally named `{}`.

---

<sup>**A sidenote :** The positional parameter inside bash shell should be double quoted to deal with non-standard filenames, say those with spaces and so.</sup>

---

**Edit**

To **NOT** pay the extra cost of invoking multiple sub-shells, we can further improve the `exec` part  like below

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec bash -c 'for arg; do wc -c <"$arg"; done' _ {} +
```

---

<sup>Courtesy [@Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) suggestion.</sup>

---

Comment: I'd consider `-print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' name; do wc -c <"$name"; done`, or such. Right now we're paying a lot of extra cost to start not just a `wc` instance but also a bash shell per-file.

Comment: Or perhaps `-exec bash -c 'for arg; do wc -c <"$arg"; done' _ {} +`, to pass as many filenames as possible to each copy of bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Great suggestions..  I am taking the second suggestion to edit my answer.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the redirection, you could do it in a subshell:

```
find / -type f -name "*.c" -exec sh -c 'wc -c < "{}"' \;
```

Edit: don't do this - see comments below!

Comment: Putting the `{}` inside an argument passed to `-c` incurs security vulnerabilities. You'll have a very, *very* bad day if someone checks a file created with `touch '$(rm -rf ~).c'` into the codebase you're running this on. Much safer to pass it out-of-band, as in the answer by sjsam.

Comment: (Also, the POSIX standard for `find` doesn't guarantee that `{}` will be replaced if it's a substring as opposed to the entirety of an argument. Works on common implementations, including GNU and BSD, but it may well be problematic on older or small embedded systems).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hmm,, without the double quotes too this is problematic as it can't deal with file names with say, spaces in them. So I suggested that the argument be in the double quotes. No we have security issues, I guess, the out-of-band method is the only failsafe/suggested method then.

Comment: @sjsam, right -- some people try single quotes instead, but those are easily countered by an attacker putting literal single quotes in the filenames (consider `touch $'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\'.c'` to create an attack that works both ways). Keeping data out-of-band from code is the right way to go.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for the info, that's good to know. I'm trying to test it myself, but I can't actually create this file with your `touch` command: `touch: cannot touch '$(rm /tmp/test).c': No such file or directory`, how can I create this file?

Comment: @Tom, the test case there requires you to have a directory named `$(rm ` in which to create a subdirectory `tmp`, and for a file named `test).c` to be created therein. There's a reason my example didn't have any slashes. Consider `touch $'$(touch pwned)\'$(touch pwned)\'.c'` if you don't want to go to the trouble of creating some oddly-named directories.

Comment: @Tom, ...or, for your original test case: `mkdir -p '$(rm /tmp' && touch '$(rm /tmp/test).c'` (no need for the `$''` syntax since we aren't putting literal single quotes in the names).